# Developing a custom filesystem for an operating system

Tags: c, gcc, osdev

I am developing an operating system using C, Assembler and the GCC Cross Compiler. I have already implemented a working kernel that prints to the screen and allows the user to type in some simple commands. I have already looked into some file systems such as FAT32 and LFS. What other options do I have about implementing my very own filesystem?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow. I recommend you start with FUSE.

Comment: Do you have working device drivers? Otherwise you're stuck with a ram disk.

Comment: I don't have any working device drivers yet but I will look into that.

Comment: There is support for dozens of file systems in the linux source code, why don't use start there?

Comment: Use an open source, BSD/MIT license filesystem. No need to reinvent the wheel. FreeBSD UFS perhaps? if your OS is GPL compatible, just use ext2/3/4 or XFS.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always [Practical File System Design with the Be File System](http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: This eBook has lots of info about file system concepts. It seems to provide me with lots of code as well.